# Lazy evaluation in parallel queries

Tags: c#, .net, linq, parallel-processing, plinq

I have following code:

```
static IEnumerable<int> foo()
{
    int den = 0;
    yield return 10;
    yield return 10;
    yield return 10;
    yield return 10 / den;
    yield return 10 / den;
}
static public void Main()
{
    foreach (var item in foo().AsParallel().Take(3))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

This code fails (because actually unused elements of collection will be computed - plinq computes chunks of data). Does .Net support real "lazy" parallelization (without precomputation of chunks with unused elements)?

Note: it is just simple example. I understand, `AsParallel` should be used for big data to avoid overhead.

Comment: Am I missing something? You just need to change the order, right?  `foo().Take(3).AsParallel()`

Comment: What is difference?

Comment: `AsParallel()` has no knowledge of what's coming after it, so it parallelize all items in the collection, thus the error.  `Take(3).AsParallel()` takes the first 3 elements then parallelize them, thus no error.

Comment: @wdosanjos, As I understood, in your case, result collection will not be processed in parallel way

Comment: If `AsParallel` is last operation then result type will be `ParallelEnumerableWrapper` which just give simple sequental enumerator

Comment: @LmTinyToon Any operations *after* the `Take` would be.  The `Take` itself wouldn't be.  Note that there's no meaningful parallelization that can be done for a `Take` operator.

Comment: @Servy, I misunderstood you little bit. Why does operations after the `Take` will be processed in parallel way?

Comment: @LmTinyToon you need to do something after `AsParallel()` that causes the query to be parallelized.  For example, `foo().Take(3).AsParallel().ForAll(Console.WriteLine)` instead of a `foreach` loop.

Comment: @LmTinyToon Because you used `AsParallel`...That's what it does, it indicates that LINQ operations following it will be processed in parallel (to the best of their ability).

Answer (score 1):

If you prohibit the precomputation of chunks then you can't do any work in parallel.  The *only* way to parallelize any of the streaming operators is for them to query more items of the data source than they can be sure that they need and pre-compute their values.  If you cannot allow any pre-computation of data then you, by definition, can't do any of the processing for any of these operators in parallel, and simply need to use regular LINQ operations rather than PLINQ.

Comment: But why plinq processes extra unused elements? Why does it precompute extra elements? I cannot understand this idea. I cannot understand why storing computed chunks will give better preformance in parallel way.

Comment: @LmTinyToon If you only process the items that have been asked for, then *by definition* you're only ever processing one item at a time, because only one item at a time is ever asked for.  The only possible way you can have multiple items to process is to ask for more items than have yet been asked of you.